# Unable to remove style

Tags: jquery, html, css

The "header" element in my website - through media query in css - when the browser window is smaller than 500px, gets “left: -100%”. At the same time a “show menu” button appears. When clicked this happens:

```
$('.showMenu').click(function(){
    $('header').animate({left: 0}, 'fast,swing');
});
```

The “header” then enters from the left with a smooth animation. The “show menu” button is also removed and a “hide menu” button appears. When clicked this happens:

```
$('.hideMenu').click(function(){
    $('header').animate({left: "-100%"}, 'fast,swing');
});
```

This pushes the "header" to the left by making direct changes to the HTML:

```
<header style="left: -100%;">
```

**Here comes my problem.**

If the browser window is larger than 500px I want the header to return to its original style, which is “left: 0”. The following jquery should work but it doesn’t overide the new style that the “header” just aquired:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 500) {
        $('header').css({left: 0});
    }
});
```

I’ve also tried with no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 500) {
        $('header').removeAttr( 'style' );
    }
});
```

I’ve got no problem if I just play with the browser size. But if I click the button to hide the menu and the “header” aquires that new style, I can’t seem to be able to overide this and make the menu appear again.

Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you give us a sample file?

Comment: $('header').css({left: 0}); use "quotes" to left attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to trigger the event whenever the browser window is resized ... so rather than putting your code in document ready you should put your code in windows resize function

```
  $(window).resize(function(){ 
     if($(window).width() > 500) {
            $('header').css({left: 0});
        }
    // and whatever stuffs you want to do ... 
    });
```

and also you might want to check for the window width for the very first time when page is loaded for first time . Hence you need to add the condition outside resize function also . the full code will be

```
    function headerEvents(){
     if($(window).width() > 500) {
                    $('header').css({left: 0});
                }
    }



   $(document).ready(function(){
    headerEvents();
     $(window).resize(function(){ 
             headerEvents();         
            // and whatever stuffs you want to do ... 
            }); 
    });
```

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the 2 different styles in 2 different css classes.
When the browser is > 500 then you add or remove a cascade style

(p.s. you need to trigger your event ALSO at window resize!)